# When to use sentRequestHeader method of XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

What i am trying to  do is grab an uploaded image file and print out the $_FILES array to show different properties of the image.I was trying with ajax so that i don't need to refreash the page when submitting the form.First i used this line of code in my ajax call

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

But i received an empty array in response to the call.Then i commented out this particular line of code and i get an array filled with all the necessary information about the uploaded image.

> array(1) { ["image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "Koala.jpg"
>   ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24)
>   "C:\xampp\tmp\php8E8B.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(780831) }
>   }

So my question when to use setRequestHeader() mehtod.When it must be there and when it mustn't?thanks !!

```
<html>

<body>
<form id='form'>

   <input type='button' value='submit' name='submit' id='btn'>
   <input type='file' name='image' id='image'>
</form>
<span id='output'></span>
<script>

   function callajax(e){
         var form=document.getElementById('form');

       var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

       xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
          if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
               document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
          }
       }
       var data=new FormData(form);
       xhr.open("POST", "call.php", true)
     // xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       xhr.send(data);
   }

   document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',callajax,false);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

php::

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `setRequestHeader` when you need to set a request header.

The browser will set the `Content-Type` request header automatically according to the algorithm described in [the send method](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send()-method) in the spec.

If you set a Content-Type header then one of three things will happen:

- You will duplicate the auto-detection
- You will correct an incorrect mime type
- You will set an incorrect mime type

When you pass a FormData object to `send()` it will encode it using `multipart/form-data`.

Setting it explicitly to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` will set an incorrect MIME type. PHP will try to decode the data using the algorithm for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and fail. It then won't populate `$_POST` or `$_FILES`.

> if it sets an incorrect mime type,then why we need it..

It isn't clear what you mean by "it" here.

If you pass a FormData object and **don't** override the Content-Type header, then the XmlHttpRequest algorithm will set the correct Content-Type header.

> and what is all about sending a header

There are many headers that have many meanings. The Content-Type header tells the server what type of data is in the body of the request.

Comment: thanks ! if it sets an incorrect mime type,then why we need it..and what is all about sending a header